# Error with wp and sass/compass

Tags: wordpress, sass

So, I'm trying to set up my wp theme for use with sass.

I've renamed style.css to style.scss and put it in a folder called 'sass'. 
Then I made a file called config.rb. In it I wrote

```
/* config.rb in the theme's root. */ 
css_dir = "/"
sass_dir = "sass"
output_style = :compressed
```

I then try to use compas.app to watch the folder (that is on a FTP server, mounted in Finder). I choose the root folder of the theme and press ok. After two seconds I get an error:

'(RegexpError) target of repeat operator is not specified: /* config.rb in the theme's root. */
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1112:in `eval'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_0.12/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in`parse_string'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_0.12/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:15:in `_parse'
org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1139:in`open'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:296:in `open'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/Java/lib/java/jruby-complete.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:32:in`open'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_0.12/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `_parse'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_0.12/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:7:in`new_from_file'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_0.12/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:204:in `with_defaults'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_0.12/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:6:in`new_from_file'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_0.12/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:42:in `configuration_for'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_0.12/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:97:in`add_project_configuration'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_0.12/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:31:in `add_project_configuration'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_0.12/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in`configure!'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_0.12/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in `initialize'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_0.12/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:37:in`initialize'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/Java/compass-app.jar!/ui/tray.rb:417:in `watch'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/Java/compass-app.jar!/app.rb:207:in`try'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/Java/compass-app.jar!/ui/tray.rb:412:in `watch'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/Java/compass-app.jar!/ui/tray.rb:153:in`open_dir_handler'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/Java/compass-app.jar!/ui/tray.rb:71:in `run'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/Java/compass-app.jar!/main.rb:115:in`run_tray'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/Java/compass-app.jar!/main.rb:131:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1062:in`require'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/Java/compass-app.jar!/main.rb:1:in `(root)''

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to debug it.

First, download your theme to a local drive and run `compass compile` on it.

Then run Compass.App on it.

Then run `compass watch` on the remote folder.

On which step does the problem occur?